# Return view while process data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I never programmed a async method in my life before.
I just read the following website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

But it isn't totally clear for me...

I want a functie to return a view while processing data. Without the user having to wait on de data to process before the view will load.
So return the view and keep processing the data in the background....

So is the following pseudocode possible with async programming?

```
public async actionresult page(object obj)  
    {   
       SQLUploadToDatabase(obj);  

       string x = DoOtherWork();  

       return View(x);  
    }  



Public void SQLUploadToDatabase(object obj)
{
      conn = SQL.openconnection; 
      conn.inserttotable(obj);
}
```

Comment: This is not related to async/await. Also it probably is not good practice unless you do not care about the result (ie. what happens if your statement fails or if the iis app pool is restarted). There are plenty of SO q/a's about offloading long running processes on asp.net / mvc, I suggest you search on that.

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not what async controller methods do.  You would have to kick off some background process that does the upload and return something to the client immediately.  Tons of different ways to run your background processes.  Letting the user know the result then becomes an issue.  Many ways of accomplishing that as well.  Lots.  Many.

Comment: While reading messages above i think i have searched for the wrong combination of words. 
i will have a look what i find when using "offloading long running processes" as search key. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for fire and forget approach. If you do not care about background job success or fail, you can just use -

```
public ActionResult Page(object obj)
{
    Task.Run(() => SQLUploadToDatabase(obj));

    string x = DoOtherWork();

    return View(x);
}
```

If you want to know whether it is success or fail, you want to use background  scheduler like HangFire or Quartz.NET. You can read more at [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for!  I have already developed a way to check the status by checking a value in a different process. so i don't care about a fail or succes in this code. I am surprised by how easy your pseudo code looks. I am going to try this as soon as possible.

Comment: Be mindful that `Task.Run` will pull a thread from the asp.net threadpool so if enough of these run you can starve requests.  If that might be a problem, you'd have better luck with using the old school `Thread`.

Comment: Task.Run makes me lose the HTTPContext  I need that inside the task.  This is why i want to keep the process running in the actionresult